# Why doesn't this python decorator work?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand decorators in python. I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
def decorator(func):
    def logger(*args, **kwargs):
        print "start logging"
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "end logging"
    return logger

@decorator
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
```

If I call `add(2,3)` the output will be:

```
start logging
end logging
```

However if I modify my code and write `return func(*args, **kwargs)` in the definition of `logger` it works but then `end logging` is not written on the output.

Comment: A function ends when you `return`... Assign the result of calling the function, *then* print, *then* return that result.

Comment: The `logger` function *must* return the value of `func`, but it can't do it until the end. Now think a little, how could you possibly save the result of the `func` call, so you could `return` it later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *capture* the return value in a variable, and return it after printing:

```
def decorator(func):
    def logger(*args, **kwargs):
        print "start logging"
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print "end logging"
        return result
    return logger
```

Decorators are not special here; it's just a function calling another function.